# Inject on ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a hash based on an ActiveRecord query in a model
`quit_reasons` the return from a has_many associations

```
reasons = quit_reasons.inject({}) do |result, element|
  result[element.name] = element.id
end
```

I keep getting

```
undefined method `[]=' for 2:Fixnum
```

and I have no idea why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix is :-

```
reasons = quit_reasons.inject({}) do |result, element|
  result[element.name] = element.id
  result
end
```

The reason is, `Hash#[]=`, returns the *value* is being assigned to the *key*. As this method `Hash#[]=` is your block's last statement, return *value* of `#[]=` is being assigned to the `result`, which is causing the error for the next `Hash#[]=` call.

I always try to use thus `#each_with_object` if I can.  Though the object is passed as the first parameter and the result as the second (i.e. the opposite way around to inject)

```
reasons = quit_reasons.each_with_object({}) do |element, result|
  result[element.name] = element.id
end
```

This one of the most *important difference* between `#inject` and `#each_with_object`.

Comment: Heh, thanks.  Just realised that.  Feel like such a fool now, especially as I've been sitting here looking at it for about 10 minutes.  Time for a coffee

Comment: Thanks for the added infor about `each_with_object`, not come across that before

Comment: amended your answer as looking at each_with_object it passes the arguments in the other way around (just in case future people look at this and get stuck)

Comment: @Baloo Opps. blind copy-paste I did.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Damn I'm an idiot.

I forgot to return the result

```
reasons = quit_reasons.inject({}) do |result, element|
  result[element.name] = element.id
  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The block needs to return the result. What can be achieved by using `merge` or `update` on the hash:

```
reasons = quit_reasons.inject({}) do |result, element|
  result.update(element.name => element.id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I've marked Arup's answer as correct as he answered first but updating or merging works too.